# How do I store Strings in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm fairly new to C and I designed a simple experiment to help me understand basic I/O.

I'm creating a program that will read data from a basic .txt file, store it, and allow me to manipulate it.

In this case, I'm using MyAnimals.txt which contains:

```
4 Dogs
3 Cats
7 Ducks
```

Here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 main()
 {
    char szInputBuffer[50]; //Buffer to place data in 
    FILE *pfile;

    int i;
    char szAnimalName[20]; //Buffer to store the animal name string
    char *pszAnimalNames[3]; //An array of 4 pointers to point to the animal name strings
    int  iAmountOfAnimal[3]; //An array to store the amount of each animal


    pfile = fopen("MyAnimals.txt", "r");
    printf("According to MyAnimals.txt, there are:\n");

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        fgets(szInputBuffer, 50, pfile);
        sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%d %s", &iAmountOfAnimal[i], szAnimalName);
        pszAnimalNames[i] = szAnimalName;
        printf("%d %s\n", iAmountOfAnimal[i], pszAnimalNames[i]);
    }

    printf("The number of %s and %s is %d\n", pszAnimalNames[1], pszAnimalNames[2], iAmountOfAnimal[1] + iAmountOfAnimal[2]);
    printf("The number of %s and %s is %d\n", pszAnimalNames[0], pszAnimalNames[1], iAmountOfAnimal[0] + iAmountOfAnimal[1]);
}
```

However my output is:

```
According to MyAnimals.txt, there are:
4 Dogs
3 Cats
7 Ducks
The number of Ducks and Ducks is 10
The number of Ducks and Ducks is 7
```

Why is it that the value pszAnimalNames[0, 1, and 2] points to "Ducks" by the end of the program?

Desired output is:

```
According to MyAnimals.txt, there are:
4 Dogs
3 Cats
7 Ducks
The number of Cats and Ducks is 10
The number of Dogs and Cats is 7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char *pszAnimalNames[3];
```

does not allocate any memory for the text. So every time you assign something to it, you are actually pointing to `szAnimalName`, which is 'Ducks' at the end of the program.

This line:

```
pszAnimalNames[i] = szAnimalName;
```

actually says that `pszAnimalNames[i]` should take the value that `szAnimalName` points to. So at the end of the loop, every value in `pszAnimalNames` points to the *same* location. Even though you are changing the contents of  `szAnimalName`, its location remains the same.

that line should instead say

```
pszAnimalNames[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
memcpy(pszAnimalNames[i], szAnimalName, 20);
```

That will allocate space for the string and *copy* it to the list of names. Then at the end of your program, you will need to free the memory:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    free(pszAnimalNames[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should comment why one has to use malloc and that the memory allocated has to be freed.